# Query model against value within a list

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

When I query a user from its email:

```
User.findOne({email: 'a@a.com'}).done(function(err, u){console.log(u.sessionTokens);})
```

I got its tokens list:

```
[ { token: '8dfe6aa0-2637-4b3f-9a3c-3ae8dc225b77',
    issuedAt: Tue Jan 14 2014 14:40:22 GMT+0100 (CET) } ]
```

But when I query a token within this list it does not retrieve the user:

```
User.findOne({'sessionTokens.token':'8dfe6aa0-2637-4b3f-9a3c3ae8dc225b77'}).done(function(err, u){console.log(u);})

=> undefined
```

Any ideas ?
Does the `User.findOne({'sessionTokens.token':'8d...77'})` is a correct query ?

**EDIT**

My User model is something like:

```
module.exports = {

  schema: true,

  attributes: {

    email: {
      type: 'email',
      required: true
    },

    encryptedPassword: {
      type: 'string'
    },

    sessionTokens: {
      type: 'array'
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

sessionToken is an attribute of type Array. This array contains several object like:

```
{ token: '8dfe6aa0-2637-4b3f-9a3c-3ae8dc225b77',
issuedAt: Tue Jan 14 2014 14:40:22 GMT+0100 (CET) }
```

**EDIT**

I've tested with mongo-sails instead of mongo-disk, this is working fine but as Chad pointed this out, it depends of the adapter used.

Answer (score 2):

With the help of robdubya & sfb_ in #sailsjs@freenode, we discussed a solution for this a bit. The answer depends on the adapter you are using. The adapter that I am most familiar with is the mysql adapter, and in that adapter, the 'array' attribute type gets serialized to the database as a JSON string. So in that case, using the 'contains' modifier on the query of the model would allow you to find the record you are looking for:

```
var criteria = {
  sessionToken: {
    contains: '8dfe6aa0-2637-4b3f-9a3c-3ae8dc225b77'
  }
};

User.findOne(criteria).done(function (err, user) {
  ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try this approach. Usually I use sails-mongo, but in the present case I only use sails-memory.

Comment: I've tested the criteria approach but this is not working, the user is not found. Shouldn't the criteria specify that "token" attributes of sessionTokens object should be used within the filter ? (sessionTokens is an array of object where each object has 2 attriubutes (token and issuedAt)).

Comment: But then you'd have to deal with the specifics of how mysql serialized your object when it stored it. In particular escaping the quotes around the keys and values should be fun. But you could change the "contains" value to "token: 'dgtetg...'".